# How to get the values of a System.out.print in a void function and use it in another function?

Tags: java, swing

I have a function that is a void function. 
It shows a `System.out.print` result on screen when it's called.

Is there a way to use the results of the `System.out.print` and put it on a JTextField?

For example:

`function.getList();` Function that contains all the code and the Sysout result

which results in:

"Some text"

Then, I would like to use something like this:

`textField = new JTextField();`

`textField.setText(function.getList());`

Edit: Since there's no reasonable way to get the values of the `System.out.print` output, I changed the `function.getList()` method to return a ArrayList of Strings.

Comment: Is making the function return a string not an option?

Comment: Calling a function `foo.getSomething()` and having it be void seems like bad practice anyway, as "get" generally implies that you are returning some value.

Comment: It's actually just listSomething, but I see your point

Comment: It's a really obnoxious to return a string, because it not always shows a string

Comment: Fair enough, I was just going off what you provided in your example. While I can't say I know the exact specifics of your situation, I still think that returning a string is the easiest way to handle this. You can always just pass an empty string in event of no output.

Comment: One thing, what would you do to store the strings on the output of the function, if inside the function there's a Loop that generates these strings.

Comment: Edit your question, comments are not a good place for this

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `function.getList()` returns `String` use the [`JTextField.setText()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String)) and revalidate component:

```
textField.setText(function.getList());
textField.revalidate();
```

There is no need to create new `JTextField`, just set text on existing one.

You could redirect `System.out` by calling [`System.setOut()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)) with your own `PrintWriter` backed by `StringWriter` but please don't do it, it's a hack.

Comment: Yeah that hack sounds like a major headache. Unless OP has a really good reason for not returning something this is definitely preferred.

Comment: I tried using this. Also is this really a bad thing to do?

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro this is an ancient API which was kept for compatibility reason. The only place in the JVM which breaks language spec and let's you set a `final` variable to a new value (`System.out` is `final`). The approach is also not thread-safe, what if more than one thread writes to `System.out`? Just don't.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest changing the function to return a String instead of having it be void, and then `textField.setText(function.getList());` should work.

If you want to keep the text printing to the console, then you could put what `System.out.print()` was printing in a String variable and pass that String variable to it.